# Append new element from XML to HTML, then target new element using one function/callback

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, callback

I have a web page that has a dropdown menu and an empty div. When the user makes a selection from the dropdown, a table element will be inserted into the div. The table is taken from one of two xml files, depending on the user's dropdown choice. Once the table is inserted into the div, another function should run that counts how many columns the inserted table has.

I can't use promises, because I need to support IE and don't want to include a third-party library. So I'm looking at callbacks.

As it is, I can get the table to be inserted properly, but since the second function is called from the same event, it doesn't see the table "yet" when it tries to count the columns.

EDIT for clarity: If I try to call the numberOfColumns function at the end of the getTable function, it tells me "Unable to get Property 'rows' of undefined or null reference".

Thanks in advance!

Note: The code is simplified from the actual situation.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
  <select id="choice" onchange="getTable("choice")">
    <option>Fruits</option>
    <option>Vegetables</option>
  </select>
  <div id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the XML code from Fruits.xml:

```
<table id="newTable">
  <tr><th>Item</th><th>Size</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Apple</td><td>Small</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Melon</td><td>Large</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the XML code from Vegetables.xml:

```
<table id="newTable">
  <tr><th>Item</th><th>Size</th><th>Price</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Onion</td><td>Small</td><td>$1.00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cabbage</td><td>Large</td><td>$2.00</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the Javascript code that gets and inserts the table to #mainDiv:

```
function getTable(dropdownID) {
  var choiceIndex = document.getElementById(dropdownID).selectedIndex;

  switch(choiceIndex) {
    case 1:
      var fileName = "Fruits.xml"
      break;
    case 2:
      var fileName = "Vegetables.xml"
      break;
  }

  var request;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  request.open("GET", fileName);

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
      var tableCode = request.responseText;
      document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = tableCode;
    }
  }

  request.send();

}
```

Here's the JavaScript code that gets the number of columns from the table:

```
function numberOfColumns(tableID) {
  var target = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var numCols = target.rows[0].cells.length;
  console.log("The table has " + numCols + " columns!");
}
```

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: See the third paragraph: both functions (getTable and numberOfColumns) need to be called during the "onchange" event, but the table isn't really in the HTML yet when the numberOfColumns function runs, so it gives an error saying there are no rows in undefined or null.

Comment: Edited the post to clarify.

Comment: check the answer now. if you have any queries, just make a comment. I am not sure when I will be able to give a reply coz now itself time is 10 in night and I didn't left office because of this. :-)

Comment: Thank you, that works. Is using a timer like that the best/only way to accomplish this? Also, I need multiple functions to be called in sequence from the "onchange" event (i.e., now that I know how many columns there are, I need to be a checkbox for each one, etc.). Should I just continue to nest all of the function calls in your setTimeout's anonymous function?

Comment: Yes. After all, just clear the timeout function. Consider marking as answer for future visitors

Comment: Also you need to change the time as per your need. If it is in local machine , 500 mS is enough. But the time is not enough for remote users.

Comment: Is there a way to do it so that each function runs automatically once the previous function is completed, rather than setting a time interval?

Comment: check the last part of answer.

Comment: It happens only on Ajax codes. Rest of JS behaviour is same

Comment: It looks like that works! I'll continue to test and will update next week. Thanks very much for your help : )

Comment: anytime. just ping me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is , the **function is executed before the response is obtained from AJAX**.

add the below code to call the `function numberOfColumns` at last of the getTable`

```
var a=setTimeout(function(){numberOfColumns("newTable"); clearTimeout(a);},500);
```

> set a Timeout function to invoke the function after 500 milliseconds. Assume that the response is obtained within that timespan. If you are hosting it in WWW,
>   set the time to 2000/3000 or even more etc. because the internet speed may vary.

Full code

```js
function getTable(dropdownID){
  var choiceIndex = document.getElementById(dropdownID).selectedIndex;

  switch(choiceIndex) {
    case 1:
      var fileName = "Fruits.xml";
      break;
    case 2:
      var fileName = "Vegetables.xml";
      break;
  }
  var request;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  request.open("GET", fileName,true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200)) {
      var tableCode = request.responseText;
      document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = tableCode;
    }
  }

  request.send();
  var a=setTimeout(function(){numberOfColumns("newTable"); clearTimeout(a);},500);
}



function numberOfColumns(tableID) {
  var target = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var numCols = target.rows[0].cells.length;
  console.log("The table has " + numCols + " columns!");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <select id="choice" onchange="getTable('choice');">
    <option>Fruits</option>
    <option>Vegetables</option>
  </select>
  <div id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
```

```html
//Fruits.xml
<table id="newTable">
  <tr><th>Item</th><th>Size</th><th>Price</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Onion</td><td>Small</td><td>$1.00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cabbage</td><td>Large</td><td>$2.00</td></tr>
</table>


//Vegetables.xml
<table id="newTable">
  <tr><th>Item</th><th>Size</th><th>Price</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Onion</td><td>Small</td><td>$1.00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cabbage</td><td>Large</td><td>$2.00</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Edit as per comment in question**

Alternatively, you can try

```
if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200)) {
  var tableCode = request.responseText;
  document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = tableCode;
  numberOfColumns("newTable");
}
```